# Creating process dump on the fly when it crashes

Tags: windows, process, dump

Is there a way one can force the process to create dumps whenever it crashes. I have an exe running in different OS's and I would like to create a dump whenever it crashes.

By different OS's, I mean different versions of Windows. On XP, you can create using DrWtsn or in > Vista, one can use windows error reporting services. I want to force it programmatically.

Comment: Linux creates a `core` file.  What more do you want?

Comment: Sorry, more precisely, by different OS's I meant different versions of Windows. On XP, you can create using DrWtsn or in > Vista, one can use windows error reporting services. I want to force it programmatically.

Comment: If you mean different version of Windows, please say that.  (1) Please **Edit** your question.  (2) Please change the tags.  (3) Please fix the title.  If you don't say "Windows", then your question appears silly.  Please **Edit** the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MinidumpWriteDump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It doesn't even have to be called from the same process, although there are some restrictions on that.

You should also make sure you archive your application symbols appropriately if you are getting minidumps from deployed applications. See [Symbol Server and Symbol Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
 on MSDN.

Comment: Example code and description could be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux you can set core limit using

ulimit -c [core size]

example :

ulimit -c 6000

you need to create a wrapper script for the application or set it in terminal.

or if you have source code you can use function

`setrlimit` to set core limit.